# Pandas: Merge data frames without connection column

Tags: pandas, merge

I have 3 different data frames with only one column each - one with the 'store' column, another with the 'brand' column and the other with the 'date' column.
I intend to obtain all possible combinations. I tried with the merge function, but since I don't have a connection column, I couldn't.

Can someone tell me what command to use?

Thank you.

Comment: You should add your sample codes and data in your question so people could reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) by `Series` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'store':list('abc')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'brand':list('zyzw')})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-01-10','2010-09-06']})

df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['store'], df2['brand'], df3['date']),
                  columns=['store','brand','date'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   store brand        date
0      a     z  2019-01-10
1      a     z  2010-09-06
2      a     y  2019-01-10
3      a     y  2010-09-06
4      a     z  2019-01-10
5      a     z  2010-09-06
6      a     w  2019-01-10
7      a     w  2010-09-06
8      b     z  2019-01-10
9      b     z  2010-09-06
10     b     y  2019-01-10
11     b     y  2010-09-06
12     b     z  2019-01-10
13     b     z  2010-09-06
14     b     w  2019-01-10
15     b     w  2010-09-06
16     c     z  2019-01-10
17     c     z  2010-09-06
18     c     y  2019-01-10
19     c     y  2010-09-06
20     c     z  2019-01-10
21     c     z  2010-09-06
22     c     w  2019-01-10
23     c     w  2010-09-06
```

For oldier pandas versions add `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df1['store'], df2['brand'], df3['date'])),
                  columns=['store','brand','date'])
```